# Chain ID & Network ID for Ethereum private network

Tags: private-blockchain, networkid

I have question regarding the Chain ID and Network ID for Ethereum Private networks as I have been unable to find a solution online. I am just confused as to how the network IDs and Chain IDs are allocated? Is it first come first served? And what would happen if I used the Network ID 1 and Chain ID 1 for my private network? How do I choose one and, if I were to choose a random one how would I prevent someone from using/connecting to it?

Just a quick side note. In terms of public networks, what is the point of specifying different chain IDs when we could just specify a different Network ID?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the repo https://github.com/ethereum-lists/chains that collects the existing chains. There's no central authority that controls chain ids, anyone can use any number.

For a private network using any number should be fine. As a suggestion avoid using the same ids than mainnet and principal testnets.

Comment: Hi Ismael, thank you a lot for your answer,
So this list that is in github is it first come first serve? Do I just choose a random number and hope that no one has ever used it?

Also what would be the point of using a different Network ID?

Comment: @AfonsoLopodeCarvalho There are some rules in their README file which chain will have precedence in case of a conflict. If you have another doubt it is better to create a separate question.